# Выборка из 4 таблиц в одну результатирующую

Tags: sql, mysqli

### Имеется 4 таблицы, которые нужно соединить

1. Таблица **PRIVATE_CHAT**. 
В данной таблице мне нужно сгруппировать все пары **user_from** и **user_to** и отсеять все лишнее кроме записей с максимальным **id** для каждой пары, а так же вывести **count** ко всем имеющимся записям каждой пары по условию **check_text, view_notif, hidden** = 0.

| id | user_from | user_to | check_text | view_notif | hidden |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user | user_two | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | user_two | user | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | user | user_two | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | user_three | user | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 5 | user | user_three | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 6 | user | user_three | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Желаемый результат:

| id | user_from | user_to | check_text | view_notif | hidden | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | user | user_two | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| 6 | user | user_three | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

---

2. Далее из таблицы **USERS** по предыдущему результату необходимо выбрать значение обоих столбцов по условию `(private_chat.user_from = users.user_login AND private_chat.user_from <> 'user') OR (private_chat.user_to = users.user_login AND private_chat.user_to <> 'user')`

| user_login | user_icon |
| --- | --- |
| user | img/user.svg |
| user_two | img/user_two.svg |
| user_three | img/user_three .svg |

Желаемый результат:

| id | user_from | user_to | check_text | view_notif | hidden | COUNT | user_login | user_icon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | user | user_two | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | user_two | img/user_two.svg |
| 6 | user | user_three | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | user_three | img/user_three.svg |

3. Из 3й таблицы **PRIVATE_SETTING**  необходимо получить значение столбцов **status, status_check** по условию из пред. результата `user_login = private_setting.user`

| status | status_check | user |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | user_two |
| 1 | 1 | user_three |
| 1 | 1 | user |

Желаемый результат:

| id | user_from | user_to | check_text | view_notif | hidden | COUNT | user_login | user_icon | status | status_check |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | user | user_two | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | user_two | img/user_two.svg | 1 | 0 |
| 6 | user | user_three | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | user_three | img/user_three.svg | 1 | 1 |

---

4. Из 4й таблицы **ACTIONS_PRIVATE**  необходимо получить значение столбца **time_ban** по условию из пред. результата `user_login = actions_private.user_to AND actions_private.user_from = 'user'`

| user_from | user_to | time_ban |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user | user_two | 6 |
| user | user_three | 40 |

Итоговый желаемый результат выборки из 4х таблиц:

| id | user_from | user_to | check_text | view_notif | hidden | COUNT | user_login | user_icon | status | status_check | time_ban |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | user | user_two | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | user_two | img/user_two.svg | 1 | 0 | 6 |
| 6 | user | user_three | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | user_three | img/user_three.svg | 1 | 1 | 40 |

*Помогите пожалуйста составить структуру, чтобы выполнить выборку одним запросом.*

Comment: Выложите таблицы в виде готовых CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO. Также поясните, что должно получиться на шаге 2, если ни `user_from`, ни `user_to` не равны `'user'`.

Comment: Слегка поправил значение в таблице users. На шаге 2 мы выбираем из таблицы users значения столбцов user_icon для всех записей, где user_login != 'user'.  И в результате в желаемому результату мы прикручиваем как я указал в "желаемом результате" user_login и user_icon. 
Таблицы я предоставил в очень сжатом варианте, т.к. других столбцов там очень много, а выборка производится только по этим данным

Comment: *Таблицы я предоставил в очень сжатом варианте, т.к. других столбцов там очень много, а выборка производится только по этим данным* Ну так и оставьте только показанные поля. *На шаге 2 мы выбираем из таблицы users значения столбцов user_icon для всех записей, где user_login != 'user'.* Это не отвечает на поставленный вопрос. Добавьте в исходную таблицу запись с user_from='user_two' и user_to='user_three', по заданным условиям оно попадает в выборку шага 1, но что с ней делать на шаге 2 - неясно.

Comment: СЛОЖНА)  Оставим этот вопрос без внимания, я не знаю как еще обьяснить. спасибо

Comment: Какая ТОЧНО версия MySQL?

Comment: Вот [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YFpxzd0u) (сделано вручную), показывает 1-й шаг. Добавляешь туда недостающие таблицы (тоже вручную - авось не отвалятся) и публикуешь ссылку - будем смотреть дальше.

Comment: Версия 5.7.39-42

Comment: Но всё равно ссылку лучше удалить...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT get_last.id,
       get_last.user_from,
       get_last.user_to,
       private_chat.check_text,
       private_chat.view_notif,
       private_chat.hidden,
       get_last.`count`,
       users.user_login,
       users.user_icon,
       private_setting.status,
       private_setting.status_check,
       actions_private.time_ban
FROM private_chat
JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(id) AS id,
         'user' AS user_from,
         CASE WHEN user_from = 'user'
              THEN user_to
              ELSE user_from
              END AS user_to,
         SUM((check_text, view_notif ,hidden) = (0, 0, 0)) AS `count`
  FROM private_chat
  WHERE 'user' IN (user_from, user_to)
  GROUP BY 2, 3
  ) get_last USING (id)
JOIN users ON get_last.user_to = users.user_login
JOIN private_setting ON get_last.user_to = private_setting.user
JOIN actions_private ON actions_private.user_to = get_last.user_to
                    AND actions_private.user_from = 'user'
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pO-QVKhA)

Comment: При таком запросе группируется обязательно в user_from 'user', а мне надо сохранить последовательность изначальную как в private_chat. Я думаю пойду курить плотно строение запросов и надеюсь не схвачу рак легких. В любом случае большое спасибо

Comment: @ДениТрехо Ну вроде бы пояснения там есть, их должно быть достаточно... а чтобы сохранить запись из private_chat "как есть" - возьми эти два поля из неё, а не из подзапроса. Делов-то..